# pandas read_html not wait for page loading

Tags: python, pandas, http, web-crawler

I am trying to read a table at an URL using pandas read_html, but the table I am interested in is loaded after the other parts of the page, so the dataframe I get is like below instead of the actual content:

```
ColumnA     |     ColumnB

Still loading |    Still loading
```

So is there a way to tell read_html to wait until the table is loaded completely and then read the table?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way we can answer for sure without a specific code example, but you should be aware that **`read_html` crawls the *static* version of the HTML as it is served; it doesn't wait for JavaScript to execute** (likely what you're seeing happen in the browser when the table "loads") because the HTML crawler doesn't execute JavaScript at all.

You can also read more about common HTML-scraping gotchas with pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-html-gotchas), though these will be more relevant for performance rather than waiting for a secondary page update.

If you need to incorporate javascript updates into your crawl, you may need to look into a headless browser like [Selenium [docs]](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or headless-chrome [[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776351/creating-a-headless-chrome-instance-in-python)].