# How can I run a cron job that depends on a desktop without a permanent remote desktop connection open?

Tags: cron

I have a virtual machine on a cloud host that stays running in non-desktop mode. It has the Cinnamon desktop environment installed, but I don't typically leave the desktop environment open.

I have a cron job I'd like to run every hour which requires opening an app which requires a desktop environment (headful Chrome).

I've been able to schedule the cron job to use the desktop environment by adding the `DISPLAY` envvar in the job definition:

```
1 * * * * DISPLAY=:20 /path/to/script/to/execute
```

However, this only works when I use remote desktop software to open Cinnamon from my laptop.

I'd like to be able to leave the web server running, without having a remote desktop connection permanently open on my end, and run cron jobs that depend on a desktop environment.

Do y'all have a suggestion for running a cron job as I want to? Maybe a way to leave a desktop environment open without using a remote desktop? Or a way to open a desktop environment within a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a display attached, you'll need to find a headless system that can run with a virtual `DISPLAY`. Headless Chrome is probably the easiest for you to swap in, and has convenient python bindings [[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776351/creating-a-headless-chrome-instance-in-python)].

You might also want to look into running [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), depending on the task you need to run.

Finally, you might be interested in running a VNC server; depending on the config of your server, you can configure it to stay alive while your client disconnects. usually this is useful for temporary network hiccups, but set to a high enough timeout value, you may get the effects of a persistent, virtual, non-transient display.

Comment: Thank you for the suggesion! I was able to set up a persistent virtual non-transient display with TightVNC following this tutorial https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-a-vnc-server-on-linux/